# Problems while getting custom dimensions via API from Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

Goog day. When I try to get custom dimensions via API, I got error

> Exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/~all/webproperties/~all/customDimensions:
>   (400) Cannot query by ~all for id webPropertyId'

My code

```
$service_account_name = '<Service Email>@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$key_file_location = '<keyName>.p12';
$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $service_account_name,
    array(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS),
    $key,
    'notasecret',
    'http://oauth.net/grant_type/jwt/1.0/bearer',
    '<My email>'
);
$client->getAuth()->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
$service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
$result = $service->management_customDimensions->listManagementCustomDimensions('~all', '~all');
print_r($result);
```

Similar code for getting goals works correctly

```
$service_account_name = '<Service Email>@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$key_file_location = '<keyName>.p12';
$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $service_account_name,
    array(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS),
    $key,
    'notasecret',
    'http://oauth.net/grant_type/jwt/1.0/bearer',
    '<My email>'
);
$client->getAuth()->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
$service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
$result = $service->management_profiles->listManagementProfiles('~all', '~all');
print_r($result);
```

Both methods listManagementProfiles and listManagementProfiles get parametrs $accountId and $webPropertyId .
Could someone help, why I get error, while getting custom dimensions via API?

Comment: A note for others calling `listManagementProfiles` with the `~all` parameter, If you want a list of All accounts, properties and views you should call the [Account Summaries](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries/list) endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation `"~all"` is [specifically mentioned as valid parameter value for listManagementProfiles](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles/list?hl=en):

> Account ID for the view (profiles) to retrieve. Can either be a
>   specific account ID or '~all', which refers to all the accounts to
>   which the user has access.

but not for [listManagementCustomDimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/customDimensions/list), here is says simply

> Account ID for the custom dimensions to retrieve.

(same for property id). So your problem is quite literally what the error message says, you cannot use `"~all"` when querying custom dimensions.

So it seems that to list all custom dimensions you'd have to iterate through a list of property ids (as returned by the [properties/list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties/list) method) instead of using `"~all".`

Comment: Thanks, it works fine, when I call method with propertyID.